# Работа с изображениеями

Tags: php, mysql

При добавлении с изображениями присваивается имя <имя><формат>, а должен быть <имя>.<формат> 
Вот кусок кода отвечающий за это:

```
$dir='/bol/img/';
$format="jpeg";
$basename=basename($file);
$up_file=$dir.'.'.$basename;
echo ($up_file);
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']))
{
$n=mt_rand(0,997);
$file_path=$dir.$n.$format;
if (!file_exists($file_path))
{
```

И еще один вопросик: как правильно указать путь в $dir='/bol/img/';
А то он пишет ошибку:

```
localhost/bol/img/.5VJE21LC.jpglocalhost/bol/img/791jpeg
Warning: move_uploaded_file(localhost/bol/img/791jpeg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampplite\htdocs\bol\admin\img.php on line 45

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampplite\tmp\php5AC3.tmp' to 'localhost/bol/img/791jpeg' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\bol\admin\img.php on line 45
```

Если вообще полный путь этой папки находится `C:\xampplite\htdocs\bol\img`

Comment: Это весь твой код или есть чуть выше?
Тут у тебя не видно как ты переводишь с tmp папки в /bol/img

Comment: Это все что относится к работе с файлами. Файлы грузятся все ок. Только проблема с именами. не ставит точку между именем и расширением файла (((((

Answer (score 2):

В коде (в вопросе который) надо исправить строчку

```
$file_path=$dir.$n.$format;
```

на

```
$file_path=$dir.$n.".".$format;
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно твой код должен выглядеть так:

```
$dir='/bol/img/';
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
 $myfile = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
 $myfile_name = $dir.$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $myfile_name))
   {
      echo "Upload ok";
   }
   else
   {
   echo "error Move file";
   }
}
```